# unit test case for switch statement in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, switch-statement

```
 offerStatus(status, reason) {
        switch (status) {
            case 'CANCELLED':
                return 'Canceled';
            case 'DISCOVERY':
                return 'Discovery';
            case 'IMPLEMENTATION':
                return 'Implementation';
            case 'REVIEW':
                return 'Review';
            case 'IN_REVIEW':
                return 'Review';
            case 'ON_HOLD': {
                if (reason == 'Manual processing necessary') {
                    return 'OnHold-Manual';
                } else {
                    return 'On Hold';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: posted code is not valid Java...

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a unit test for the `offerStatus` function in Angular using the Jasmine testing framework

```
describe('offerStatus', () => {
  it('should return "Canceled" for status "CANCELLED"', () => {
    const status = 'CANCELLED';
    const reason = null;
    const result = offerStatus(status, reason);
    expect(result).toEqual('Canceled');
  });

  it('should return "Discovery" for status "DISCOVERY"', () => {
    const status = 'DISCOVERY';
    const reason = null;
    const result = offerStatus(status, reason);
    expect(result).toEqual('Discovery');
  });

  it('should return "Implementation" for status "IMPLEMENTATION"', () => {
    const status = 'IMPLEMENTATION';
    const reason = null;
    const result = offerStatus(status, reason);
    expect(result).toEqual('Implementation');
  });

  it('should return "Review" for status "REVIEW"', () => {
    const status = 'REVIEW';
    const reason = null;
    const result = offerStatus(status, reason);
    expect(result).toEqual('Review');
  });

  it('should return "OnHold-Manual" for status "ON_HOLD" and reason "Manual processing necessary"', () => {
    const status = 'ON_HOLD';
    const reason = 'Manual processing necessary';
    const result = offerStatus(status, reason);
    expect(result).toEqual('OnHold-Manual');
  });

  it('should return "On Hold" for status "ON_HOLD" and any other reason', () => {
    const status = 'ON_HOLD';
    const reason = 'Some other reason';
    const result = offerStatus(status, reason);
    expect(result).toEqual('On Hold');
  });
});
```